# Docker on AWS Windows Workspace

Tags: docker

I searched google on how to install Docker on AWS Windows Workspace but couldn't get a proper link or notes or pdf

Can someone help me on how to install Docker on AWS Windows Workspace where the PC shows Windows Sever on OS

Thanks

I tried install docker desktop but couldn't install.
I tried for portable docker but it seems docker has to be installed in host machine.